# Set axis maximum with seaborn distplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Is it possible to set the minimum and maximum displayed limits for seaborn distplots?

I am trying to loop over columns of a pandas dataframe but all my outputs get the same axes.

```
for v in var_list: 
    df[v].dropna(inplace=True) 
    var=df[v].max()
    vstar = v + "_output.png"
    splot = sns.distplot(df[v])
#    sns.plt.xlim(0, var)
    splot.figure.savefig(vstar)
    splot.autoscale()
```

I have made a few attempts with *sns.plt.xlim()* and *autoscale()* but neither seems to do the trick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want by just using `plt.xlim(0, var)` directly:

```
In [24]: np.random.seed(0)

In [25]: data = np.random.randn(1000)

In [26]: sns.distplot(data)
Out[26]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xfa291967f0>

In [27]: plt.savefig('plot1.png')
```

[image]

```
In [39]: plt.clf()

In [40]: sns.distplot(data)
Out[40]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xfa291bcd30>

In [41]: plt.xlim(-10, 10)
Out[41]: (-10, 10)

In [42]: plt.savefig('plot2.png')
```

[image]

Comment: And by the way, if you'd rather use the object oriented API and operate directly on the `Axes` that `sns.distplot` returns (which quickly becomes beneficial for more complicated plots), you could also use `splot.set_xlim(0, var)` prior to saving the figure. The end result is the same

Answer (score 2):

For `sns.histplot` and `sns.displot`, we could use the argument `binrange`:

```py
splot = sns.displot(df[v], binrange=(0, var))
```

Comment: I get an error of unexpected keyword